# Sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a compact metric space. Let:

(a) $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued continuous functions on $X$

(b) $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to a continuous function $f$ on $X$

(c) $f_n(x) \geq f_{n + 1}(x)$ for all $x \in X$ and all $n \geq 1$.

Show that $f_n \to f$.

How should I go about proving this?

Comment: What do you mean by $f_n \to f$? Surely not pointwise convergence as this is a hypothesis. So maybe uniform convergence?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: See Dini's Theorem. On [Topics In Real Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hbs1u1iexc0C&pg=PA195&dq=dini%20theorem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aOcUUYH7G4zesgaW5oD4Cw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=dini%20theorem&f=false), Theorem 3, p 193. [Elementary Real Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=vA9d57GxCKgC&pg=PA386&dq=dini%20theorem&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xOUUUcqYGYPAtQbqt4GwAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dini%20theorem&f=false), P 385. or  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).